# Ansible - Delete large amount of individual files

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I want to remove the garbage files from different folders.
(Yes, the programmers of several modules were sloppy and did not cleanup the right way, but nevermind...).

In my Ansible playbook I have the following simple tasks to delete files older than 1h and not having a specific name (pattern regex). This is why i cannot simply clear the two folder. Younger files need to stay and some files are untouchable (specified by pattern).

```
- name: cleanup | find temporary files for removal
  find:
    paths: /var/xx/yy/temporary/
    recurse: no
    file_type: file
    age: 1h
    age_stamp: mtime
    patterns:
      - '^.*(?<!index\.html)$'
    use_regex: yes
  register: xxyy_temporary_files

- name: cleanup | find public/temporary files for removal
  find:
    paths: /var/zzz/public/temporary/
    recurse: yes
    file_type: any
    age: 1h
    age_stamp: mtime
    patterns:
      - '^.*(?<!index\.html)$'
    use_regex: yes
  register: zzz_public_temporary_files

- name: cleanup | remove garbage files
  file:
    path: "{{ item.path }}"
    state: absent
  with_items:
    - "{{ xxyy_temporary_files.files }}"
    - "{{ zzz_public_temporary_files.files }}"
  loop_control:
    label: "{{ item.path }}"
```

So: I collect the files for deletion in two facts.
Then I use the Ansible file module to remove them.

The problem: there are thousands of files and folders. Getting the lists of what to delete only needs seconds. But Ansible then needs ages for the third task.

Is there a way to get this done quicker? I mean like calling the file module only  once for all. Any ideas?

Comment: What stops you from writing a simple `find` oneliner? Your problem doesn't require portability between platforms, idempotence, declarative language; nothing that Ansible offers. [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: One way would be to move the files you want to delete to a folder first and then delete the folder.

Comment: I can write the find in ansible's command module. Not using Ansible at all is not an option. Because that little tasks are part of a *very* large playbook where all that is needed what you mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rewritten with Ansibles command module (if anybody comes across this and looks for something like that):

```
- name: cleanup | remove old temporary files
  command: "find {{ item }} -type f -mmin +30 -not -name \"index.html\" -not -name \".htaccess\" -print -delete -maxdepth 1"
  register: xxx_old_tmp_files
  changed_when: xxx_old_tmp_files.stdout != ""
  with_items:
    - /var/xxx/temporary/

- name: cleanup | remove old public/temporary files
  command: "find {{ item }} -type f -mmin +30 -not -name \"index.html\" -print -delete"
  register: yyy_old_pubtmp_files
  changed_when: yyy_old_pubtmp_files.stdout != ""
  with_items:
    - /var/yyy/public/temporary/

- name: cleanup | remove old empty public/temporary folders
  command: "find {{ item }} -type d -mmin +30 -empty -print -delete"
  register: zzz_old_pubtmp_empty_folders
  changed_when: zzz_old_pubtmp_empty_folders.stdout != ""
  with_items:
    - /var/zzz/public/temporary/
```

Comment: Thank you for the workaround. I believe ansible has bug for not letting users to execute the whole loop on the remote host! It actually ssh on EVERY iteration